# ImportError raised when trying to load 'material.admin.templatetags.material_admin': cannot import name Layout

Tags: python, django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
 ...
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 30, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 48, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 113, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 130, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'material.admin.templatetags.material_admin': cannot import name Layout
```

When I run the command `python manage.py runserver_plus`, I got this error, but I can't see how to fix it. What could I modify so that it works?

Comment: Try after remove all .pyc files in project directory. If you getting same error again that means you have problem in django-material library. remove 'material' from INSTALLED_APP then check.

Comment: I tried with `find . -iname '*.pyc' | xargs rm -rf {}`, but nothing changed. This is weird, because all work for my on my friend's computer, but not on my computer.

Comment: Where does `material` come from? Which version have you installed?